# Unignore a directory in git?

Tags: git

I have a directory in my repository that is being ignored. My repository name is CI and in it is a directory .teamcity

I want this directory(.teamcity) to be a normal directory and not be ignored. How would I do that?

Comment: It's not a local repository, it's a repository on github. So when I download or clone it the folder isn't being downloaded. I want to be able to download that folder from github? (.teamcity directory) from github

Comment: When you clone a repo, you clone *the whole repo*. Git has no way of ignoring things *that way*. Are you sure you didn't get that directory? You do know that it's hidden, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `.gitignore` file in your root application folder. You should remove `.teamcity` from there.

Comment: For some reason there is no .gitignore file in the root application folder.

Comment: Can you currently see hidden files? Some operating systems will recognize any "dot files", or files that begin with "." as systemfiles, thus hiding them from view.

Comment: What is your OS? Open the terminal, go to the project directory and open the file from there. For example (Ubuntu) - `nano .gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

I have just fight with this ..

Removing the `.gitgnore` file was not enough.

I also had to remove the cache with :

```
git rm -r --cached
git add .
```